# How do I hyperlink an Excel cell to google map

Tags: excel, google-maps

"I know how to hyperlink a cell to google maps using:

http://maps.google.com/?ie=UTF8&ll=41.516804,-90.549316&spn=1.08996,2.58728&z=9

What I am try to do however is add parameters for a placemark and a label into the http:// code. So that when the map opens the placemark is at the coordinate and the is a label attached to it.

How do I go abot change the http:// code line to do this?

Thanks"

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [Google Maps Ajax](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/index.html) API in order to put markers on maps.
If you want REST API to maps+markers you will need to use the [Static Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/index.html).